# jquery load function pull certain value

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

Hi I have found a value on a website that changes every 10 minutes on the server and id like to pull that value onto my site via jquery load function im not sure I am doing it right but sample code is below.

```
$('#contentDiv').load('http://www.windfinder.com/windstatistics/beirut span#current-windspeed');
```

Comment: [***Same-Origin Policy***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it but you would need a proxy. On your local machine you can utilize Fiddler but the same job on your webpage could be done by using jQuery & YML.

[Reference](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery--net-10225)

Comment: I see how that works nice! how would I call the specific span id on that page called span#current-windspeed?

Comment: To make it even easier for you here is a jQuery [cross domain mod](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax). One you have the response you can do what you feel like. Otherwise you would have to scrape the page and then get the content of the span using $('.current-windspeed')

Comment: @uiwarrior That's a cool mod - I haven't come across that before. Worth editing and putting in your answer

Comment: i tried it but getting this error, but it not live maybe possibly why im getting the error? 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.windfinder.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

The `Same-Origin Policy` policy of browsers will prevent this from working. Basically, the browser protects users from attacks whereby injected scripts "call home" with data. There are ways around it if you control the target site, allowing certain domains to have access (not applicable here I know). More details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

However, `Same-Origin Policy` is a *browser* feature, so if you get the required value from server-side code, you'll be fine.

So:

```
JQuery  -->  Your Server --> Target Page
```

**Edit**
Just seen @uiwarrior's answer. This is the same ... act as a *proxy* for getting the data. You don't indicate the server-side language, but this would be relatively easy to using something like [Html Agility Pack](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/&ei=p3grU5ytEYv8iQe4hYGwDg&usg=AFQjCNG2MH29eft1y8OrwFMjVzPNbVc0-w&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aGc) for .NET, or [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for PHP (which is like JQuery on the server)